# What is the use of Tensorflow CentralStorageStrategy?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't understand the use of [`CentralStorageStrategy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/CentralStorageStrategy).
What advantages does it have compared to the [`MirroredStrategy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy)?

To my understanding, it's just a slower version of the [`MirroredStrategy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy), because Variables are not mirrored.